Write squared norm of function in terms of squared norm of derivative.
Consider a continuously differentiable function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ which is integrable and has expectation zero with respect to a measure $\mu$ on the space $[0,1]$, that is $\int_{[0,1]} f(x) d\mu = 0$.
Is there some way to express the $L_2$ norm of this function in terms of the $L_2$ norm of its derivative?
That is, for some $G: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ independent of $f$ is it possible to have
$$
\int_{[0,1]} f(x)^2 d\mu = G\Bigg(\int_{[0,1]} f'(x)^2 d\mu\Bigg)
$$
Impose as many regularity conditions on the function $f$ as you like, i.e. I encourage answers considering nontrivial restricted spaces of functions.
Intuitively, it feels like a continuously differentiable function with mean zero can only get so far from zero as the size of its derivative allows, but I'm having trouble pinning down the exact relationship.

For the Lebesgue measure, no such $G$ exists.
Assume on the contrary that such a $G$ exists.
First, consider $f_n(x) = \sin(2\pi n x)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $1/2 = \int_0^1 f_n(x)^2 dx = (2\pi n)^{-2} \int_0^1 f_n'(x)^2 dx$, so we should have $G(2 \pi^2 n^2) = 1/2$.
Secondly, replacing $f \mapsto \lambda^{1/2} f$ for $\lambda > 0$, we deduce $G(\lambda u) = \lambda G(u)$ for $\lambda > 0$ and $u \ge 0$.
Combining the previous two paragraphs, for $x > 0$ we would have for every $n$
$$ G(x) = G((x/2\pi^2 n^2) 2\pi^2 n^2) = (x/2\pi^2 n^2) G(2\pi^2 n^2) = x/4\pi^2 n^2,  $$
which is absurd.
